# Simple Harmonic wave-Particle velocity for a snapshot:

Tags: waves

[image: Particle velocities in a snapshot]

Is my diagram correct(vp corresponds to particle velocity). Wave equation: y=Asin(wt-kx)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Velocities and accelerations depend on the wave.

For a [wave machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE520z_ugcU), velocities and accelerations are vertical, perpendicular to the direction of the wave.

For an [ocean wave](https://pilebuck.com/highways-coastal-environment-second-edition/chapter-4-waves/), they are circular in deep water and elliptical in shallow water.

For a pressure wave like sound, or a compression wave in a spring, they are longitudinal, or along the direction of the wave.

Comment: So, my question is, is my direction of particle velocity for longitudinal waves correct(This isn't a waveform for longitudinal waves, just a displacement graph of various particles at an instant.